# Multiple redirects for multiple alerts

Tags: javascript

Let me start by saying that I'm not an expert when it comes to javascript, but I've done my research and can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong with my code. For my webpage, I've been editing a reflex related game that basically has four different alerts, based off of how quickly they press the stop button.

Here's part of my code, which will show my redirect pages, which I'm not currently being redirected to. No matter which alert you receive, it takes you to the very last one which makes me wonder where I went wrong.

```
function remark(responseTime) {
    var responseString = "";
    if (responseTime < 0.20) responseString = "well done!.";
    window.location.href = "dfgr454.php";
    if (responseTime >= 0.20 && responseTime < 0.40) responseString = "nice.";
    window.location.href = "fdkjgtry5.php";
    if (responseTime >= 0.40 && responseTime < 0.60) responseString = "could be better. ";
    window.location.href = "dfg5654f.php";
    if (responseTime >= 0.60 && responseTime < 0.80) responseString = "that's no good.";
    window.location.href = "bvcb56.php";
    if (responseTime >= 0.80 && responseTime < 1) responseString = "have you been drinking?";
    window.location.href = "dfgf643re.php";
    if (responseTime >= 1) responseString = "did you fall asleep?";
    return responseString;
}
```

If it helps (and I'm no entirely sure it will, since it didn't help me), when I edited my code to try window.open instead, all of them opened at once. Is there any way to stop this from happening? The alerts are coming up fine, but I want them to redirect to the specific window.location I'm trying to pair with them. Please and thank you, any suggestions would be perfect!

Comment: format your code with proper if(){ -- }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax is

```
if(condition1) {
    /* your code */
} else if(condition2) {
    /* other code */
}
```

So your code should look something like this:

```
function remark(responseTime)
{
    var responseString="";
    if (responseTime < 0.20) {
        responseString="well done!.";
        window.location.href="dfgr454.php";
    } else if (responseTime >= 0.20 && responseTime < 0.40) {
        responseString="nice.";
        window.location.href="fdkjgtry5.php";
    } else if (responseTime >=0.40 && responseTime < 0.60) {
        responseString="could be better. ";
        window.location.href="dfg5654f.php";
    } else if (responseTime >=0.60 && responseTime < 0.80) {
        responseString="that's no good.";
        window.location.href= "bvcb56.php";
    } else if (responseTime >=0.80 && responseTime < 1) {
        responseString="have you been drinking?";
        window.location.href="dfgf643re.php";
    } else if (responseTime >=1) {
        responseString="did you fall asleep?";
    }

    return responseString;
}
```

If you use one `if` statement after the other instead of `else if`, they are tested independendtly from each other. So if your response time is `< 0.2` it's also `< 1` which causes your unexpected results.

Comment: I feel a little foolish for not being able to figure that out on my own, but it was something I wasn't entirely sure how to execute! Thank you so much and even if the explanation is short, it's very clear and to the point. I appreciate the edited code so I can really see what I need to do for next time. This will help me a lot in the future with coding, too. Thank you. ^^